# Setup OpenGL 4 build / unittest server?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, opengl, opengl-4

I'm trying to find a solution to setting up an OpenGL build server. My preference would be to have a virtual or cloud server, but as far as I can see those only go up to 3.0/3.1 using software rendering. I have a server running Windows, but my tests are Linux specific and I'd have to run it in a VM, which as far as I know also only support OpenGL 3.1.

So, is it possible to set up a OpenGL 4 build/unittest server?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  A build server and a unit test server sound like distinct things.  Is your intent to use the software renderer explicitly, so you can validate results automatically?  For example, by scanning an offscreen texture map?

Comment: @ScottJones, Well, it's currently using a window to get a context but it renders everything offscreen & checks some pixel values (in part to test the shaders). It also has a few "integration tests" that render some parts of scenes and saves those to files. In particular the window is unpractical but glfw currently doesn't support without; also I think you can't create an opengl context without at least an X server...

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL specification does not include any pixel-perfect warranties. This means your tests may fail just by switching to the other GPU or even to the other version of the driver.

So, you have to be specific. You should test not the result of rendering, but the result of math that just precedes the submission of the primitives to the API.

Comment: I am including the driver in the tests, that makes them impure unit tests but more useful as I know when my rendering falls over or gives odd results. Odd thing though, OpenGL not giving exact warranties even though you do get exact integer output formats...